Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactoryBuilder]
I had upgraded Spring Boot version to 3.4.1. I also use spring-cloud-contract-wiremock and httpclient5. I have this RestClient configuration.
ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(requestFactory);
return RestClient.builder().requestFactory(factory)
    .requestInterceptors(interceptors -> interceptors.addAll(
        List.of(new ClientHttpRequestInterceptor(),
            new RequestResponseLoggingInterceptor())))
    .build();

On running application tests, I get this:

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.http.client.ClientHttpRequestFactoryBuilder]: Factory method 'clientHttpRequestFactoryBuilder' threw exception with message: org/apache/hc/client5/http/ssl/TlsSocketStrategy

